# why my value is always taking as string in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, types, switch-statement

I am taking the request from the user and store it in `$request` variable based on this i am fetching some key value up to this it's working fine ,after this i am passing this value to the switch case statement what it does means if the value is `double/float` type it will  do some operations inside that case , similarly for `string and integer` also .but even if i pass `integer or double/float` type it will go the `string` case only .can you please help me where did i mistake..

my api **{url}/details?limit=25&amount=99.9** sometimes amount is `99 or NinteyNine`

```
Public function run(){
$request=new Request();
$value=$request->amount;
switch(gettype($value)){
 case 'double':
    //perform some logic if type is double
   break;
 case 'string':
   //perform some logic if type is string
    break;
 default:
   //perform some logic if type is Integer 
}
}
```

what ever the value is passed it's considered as a string type only i need to fix this issue please help me..

Comment: Because you’re passing it in a URI. A URI _is_ a string. There is no concept of types in a URI. Putting `99.9` in a query string does not make it a float; it’s the literal string `99.9`.

Comment: If I use is_numeric  it's returning true

Comment: That doesn’t mean anything. There is no such type as “numeric” in PHP. The value is still a string; it just determines if “a variable is a number or a **numeric string**”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `$request->amount` will always return a string since the URL query parameters are also strings.

`is_numeric()` finds whether a variable is a number or a **numeric string**. In your case, it is returning true because it is a numeric string.

You could do:

```php
function amountType(string $amount): string {
    if (is_numeric($amount)) {
        if ((int) $amount == (float) $amount) {
            return "int";
        }

        return "float";
    }
    
    return "string";
}

$type = amountType($request->amount);

switch($type) {
    case 'float':
        //perform some logic if type is double
        break;
    case 'string':
        //perform some logic if type is string
        break;
    case 'int':
        //perform some logic if type is Integer
        break;
    default:
        // Invalid type
}
```

Snippet: https://3v4l.org/K9XVB

Alternatively, if the behaviour of `float` and `int` inputs are the same, you could also do:

```php
$amount = $request->amount;

if (is_numeric($amount)) {
    $numericAmount = (float) $amount;
    // Perform some logic if input is numeric
    return;
}

// Perform some logic if input is string
return;
```

Comment: Thanks such a great answer ☺️, I am updating my question is there any way everything in same function only inorder to write new function

Comment: If I give `99.00`its considered as a int only,it should be considered as float only na..?

Comment: @user17426459 mathematically speaking `99.00` is both an integer number and a real number so it is both. The decimal points do not have any significance since they are 0

Comment: Is there any way to match if the user enters 10.00 or 10.0 it should return float